# Instead of insert trigger issue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, sql-insert

I feel like I should have been able to do

```
SET @InsertCount = COUNT (*) FROM INSERTED WHERE ISBN = @ISBN
```

But it wouldn't let me. I tried using a `SELECT` statement instead because I saw someone else online use it but I do not know what else to do.

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('BooksTrigger') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TRIGGER BooksTrigger
GO

-- create the trigger
CREATE TRIGGER BooksTrigger 
ON Books
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
    DECLARE @ISBN INT,
            @BookInDate DATE,
            @Memo VARCHAR(100),
            @Copies INT,
            @PreyQty INT,
            @InsertISBNCount INT,
            @CurrQty INT

    SET @InsertISBNCount = (SELECT COUNT(ISBN) FROM inserted WHERE ISBN = @ISBN)
    SET @PreyQty = (SELECT COUNT(ISBN) FROM Books WHERE ISBN = @ISBN)
    SET @CurrQty = (SELECT SUM(@InsertISBNCount + @PreyQty))
    SET @Copies = (SELECT CopiesNo FROM BookInfo WHERE ISBN = @ISBN)

    IF @Copies > @CurrQty
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Inserting a copy of the book with ISBN ' + @ISBN

        INSERT INTO Books (ISBN, BookInDate, Memo)
        VALUES (@ISBN, @BookInDate, @Memo)
    END
    ELSE
        THROW 50027, 'Number of copies available for this book is less than the inserts for this book. Insert did not go through.', 1
GO

-- test
BEGIN TRY
    INSERT INTO Books 
    VALUES ('9780393248968', GETDATE(), 'test') --should print 'inserting'

    INSERT INTO Books 
    VALUES ('9780393248968', GETDATE(), 'test') --this one should throw an error as this would be the fifth book
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
END CATCH

--see if the first one inserted
SELECT * FROM Books
```

So the goal here is to create an INSTEAD OF trigger for inserting data in the Books table. I want to see if the number of books inserted in the Books table for an ISBN is more than the CopiesNo in BookInfo for that same ISBN, throw an error, otherwise insert the data with a print message that says ‘inserting…’ or something.

I am told I should see a message like this when I am done:

[image: Exprected Error Message]

But I am currently getting this:

[image: Current Message]

Here is the code to make the two tables (Books AND BookInfo)

```
--BookInfo Table
CREATE TABLE BookInfo
(
    ISBN BIGINT PRIMARY KEY CHECK (LEN([ISBN]) BETWEEN 10 AND 13),
    BookCategoryID INT,
    BookName VARCHAR(60),           
    BookAuthor VARCHAR(40),
    BookPublisher VARCHAR(40),
    BookPubDate DATE,
    BookPages INT CHECK (BookPages > 0),
    BookPrice INT CHECK (BookPrice > 0),
    CopiesNo INT DEFAULT 1 CHECK (CopiesNo > 0),
    Memo VARCHAR(100) NULL,
);

--Books Table
CREATE TABLE Books
(
    BookID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    ISBN BIGINT,
    BookInDate DATE,
    Memo VARCHAR(100) NULL, 
);
GO

ALTER TABLE Books
ADD FOREIGN KEY (ISBN) REFERENCES BookInfo(ISBN);
GO

INSERT INTO BookInfo (ISBN, BookCategoryID, BookName, BookAuthor,BookPublisher, BookPubDate, BookPages, BookPrice, CopiesNo, Memo)
VALUES (9780393248968, 1, 'Storm in a Teacup: The Physics of Everyday Life', 'Helen Czerski', 'W. W. Norton & Company', '01/10/2017', 288, 26.95, 4, 'On sale'),
       (9780062328502, 1, 'Dark Matter and the Dinosaurs: The Astounding', 'Lisa Randall', 'Ecco', '10/18/2016', 432, 17.99, 2, 'Not on Sale'),
       (9780262517263, 2, 'Grace Hopper and the Invention of the Information Age', 'Kurt Beyer', 'MIT Press', '02/01/2012', 404, 27.95, 2, 'On sale');

INSERT INTO Books (ISBN, BookInDate, Memo)
VALUES (9780393248968, '01/01/2018', 'this is a book'),
       (9780393248968, '01/01/2018', 'this is a book'),
       (9780393248968, '01/01/2018', 'this is a book'),
       (9780062328502, '01/02/2018', 'this is a book I think'),
       (9780062328502, '01/02/2018', 'this is a book I think'),
       (9780262517263, '01/03/2018', 'this is a book for sure'),
       (9780262517263, '01/03/2018', 'this is a book for sure');
```

Comment: When I say "errors" It is just supposed to spit out an error message saying it will not work but I added what my message box says after I run the code.

Comment: Dale, I tried switching the SET and SELECT at the top. I left a note of that in the original question above to showed what I did. I could be misinterpreting what you are saying though.

Comment: I think I see what you mean now Dale. I just recently updated my code above and I am now getting a different message output. Once again thanks for your input!

Comment: I thought @ISBN was the value of what was inserted I guess...

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to prevent more `Book` records being added than the number of copies configured in the `BookInfo` record for the relevant `ISBN`.

However your logic is only checking the number of `Book`'s being inserted as part of this insert statement (the `inserted` table is for this insert only). Therefore if only 4 copies of a book are allowed, but you insert them as 3 records, followed by another insert of 3 records (total 6) your trigger will allow this.

If you followed your logic to solve this you need to count the `Book`'s in both the `Book` table AND the `Inserted` table.

However you can solve the problem in a much easier way, by using an `after` trigger, counting against the `Book` table, and rolling back if the condition fails e.g.

```
create trigger BooksTrigger on Books
after Insert
as
begin
  -- if, for any BookInfo record, there exist more book records than CopiesNo, rollback
  if exists (select 1 from BookInfo BI where BI.CopiesNo < (select count(*) from Book B where B.ISBN = BI.ISBN)) begin
    ;THROW 50027, 'Number of copies available for this book is less than the inserts for this book. Insert did not go through.', 1
  end
end
```

Comment: I agree I was not taking all numbers into consideration. I just updated my code again to what I am currently working on. I am not sure what you have is exactly what I am looking for. I do need an Instead of trigger specifically. If you could look at my current code and give me your thought I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Why do you need an `instead of` trigger? As far as I can tell your code is trying to do what my code does, but your code is very complicated and doesn't yet work. Rather than continuing to modify the code, check the logic I have described in my answer and clarify that. So far nothing you have shown has suggested a need for an `instead of` trigger.

Comment: I am working on doing it your way currently. I am only using this INSTEAD OF trigger for inserting data in the Books table because its what my teacher told me to do.